# R subseting acoording to Name Column

Tags: r

I am working on Titanic data set called 'train' and I want to subset the data according to  column "Name" (note that I extract the column "Name" to just "Mr", "Miss" and "Mrs").
But when I type this :

```
f3 <- train[train$Class== 3 & train$Name == 'Miss',]
```

I get this message :

```
    > f3 
    [1] Id     Class  Name   Age    Sex    Fare   Family a     
    <0 rows> (or 0-length         row.names)
```

Comment: It is difficult to comment without a small reproducible example.  From the message, it seems like the dataset doesn't have the combination.

Comment: > str (train)
'data.frame':   714 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Id    : int  1 2 3 4 5 7 8 9 10 11 ...
 $ Class : int  3 1 3 1 3 1 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ Name  : Factor w/ 17 levels " Capt"," Col",..: 12 13 9 13 12 12 8 13 13 9 ...
 $ Age   : num  22 38 26 35 35 54 2 27 14 4 ...
 $ Sex   : Factor w/ 2 levels "female","male": 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 ...
 $ Fare  : num  7.25 71.28 7.92 53.1 8.05 ...
 $ Family: int  1 1 0 1 0 0 4 2 1 2 ...

Comment: And This Is The Head Of Dataset
   > head(train)
Class  Name Age    Sex    Fare Family 
   3    Mr  22   male  7.2500      1 
   1   Mrs  38 female 71.2833      1 
   3  Miss  26 female  7.9250      0 
   1   Mrs  35 female 53.1000      1 
   3    Mr  35   male  8.0500      0 
   1    Mr  54   male 51.8625      0 
  
Is This Enough ??

Comment: Using the data you provided, train[train$Class==3 & train$Name=='Miss',]
 Class Name Age    Sex  Fare Family
3     3 Miss  26 female 7.925      0

Comment: seems that the problem comes from a white space that the user had not seen in the data. should be closed?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your command line seems perfectly fine

```
f3 <- train[train$Class== 3 & train$Name == 'Miss',]
```

so i can't see what's wrong, maybe check that your 'name' data doesn't have for instance a dot or a blanck space after it, or some capital letter in the variable or row, etc.

Comment: Thanks For Answering But There Is No Any Space There

Comment: $ Name : Factor w/ 17 levels " Capt"," Col" -> well, there do is a blanck space before " Capt"... so maybe also before Miss?

Comment: @agenis. That could be the reason.  `str_trim` from `stringr` could be an option

Answer (score 0):

Considering that it looks like you have white spaces in the Name factors as @agenis and @akrun mention in their comments, you can use stringr:

```
library(stringr) 
train$Name <- str_trim(train$Name)
f3 <- train[train$Class== 3 & train$Name == 'Miss',]
```